# retornar json c# .net core sql

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Estou fazendo um teste com uma *aplicação de console*. Nela eu consulto o *banco de dados* e gostaria de retornar um arquivo *json* do resultado.

É possível retornar a consulta *json* sem instanciar o objeto? como posso fazer isso?

Tentei converter o retorno da consulta,  mais não deu certo:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=4.4.4.4.;Database=aaaa;user id=aaaa;password=aaaaa"))
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from depposvendas", connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    //Neste caso estou tentando converter com json.net para json o retorno do SqlDataReader
    //Sem ter que instanciar objeto
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reader);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}",output);

        }
```

Comment: Ao invés de colar uma imagem do código, poste o texto e formate como código. Fica mais fácil de sua pergunta ser encontrada pela busca do site.

Comment: Se você não quer instanciar um objeto ou usar uma biblioteca externa, que é o que eu acredito que você quis dizer, basta montar a string "manualmente".

Comment: acho que antes disso você ainda precisa aprender a utilizar o ADO.NET. Nesse link começa a explicar o `ExecuteReader` : http://www.macoratti.net/08/11/c_adn_2.htm

Comment: coloquei o codigo na descrição